# How does bash redirection work under the hood?

Tags: c, bash, process, io-redirection, heredoc

I'm trying to reimplement the bash redirection and execution part for a small project, but I don't figure out how it works.

For example :

```
cat <<limit <<limit <<limit
```

I don't know why all of them executed even an error parse show up

```
bash-3.2$ <<lim | <<lim2 <><><
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<>'
> lim
> lim2
bash-3.2$
```

in other case they didn't execute

```
bash-3.2$ <<lim | <<lim2 <><>< <<lim3
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<>'
> lim
> lim2
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Heres the source repository for bash: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/

Comment: Just start with simple input and output redirection with `<` and `>`. That will be plenty enough for a most homework-type shells.

Comment: As for what you're doing in the question, you simply use invalid and seemingly random sequences of `<` and `>`, which of course won't work.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) If you have a school (or similar) assignment, we need to see it in full, including all requirements and limitations.